# Transaction does not rollback in hibernate

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, transactions

I have a problem with rollback transaction. Below I wrote some of the configuration of beans. I do 2 SQL-queries: delete and update. And when UPDATE generates exception (constraint of foreign ket), the first query (DELETE) does not rollback. Could anyone please tell me where the problem is? I wrote only some of the configuration for sake of clarity, so if it's needed more information please let me know. Thanks in adnvance!

CONTEXT:

I have DAO layer with method removeUser:

```
public void removeUser(final Long id) {
        getHibernateTemplate().execute(new HibernateCallback() {
            @Override
            public Object doInHibernate(Session session) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
                executeUpdate("delete from table1 where user_id = ?", session, id);
                executeUpdate("update table2 set user_id = null where user_id = ?", session, id);
                return null;
            }

            private void executeUpdate(String queryString, Session session, Long... params) {
                SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(queryString);

                for (int paramIndex = 0; paramIndex < params.length; paramIndex++) {
                    Long param = params[paramIndex];
                    query.setParameter(paramIndex, param);
                }

                query.executeUpdate();
            }
        });
}
```

This method is called from within service:

```
public void removeUser(Long id) {
        userDao.removeUser(id);
}
```

This service is configured via spring:

```
<bean name="adminUserService" parent="txProxyServiceTemplate">
   ... setting properties ...     
</bean>

<bean id="txProxyServiceTemplate" abstract="true"
          class="com.xalmiento.desknet.ui.server.service.transaction.GWTTransactionProxyFactoryBean">
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager"/>
        <property name="transactionAttributes">
            <props>
                <prop key="remove*">PROPAGATION_NESTED</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
        <property name="nestedTransactionAllowed" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Which database are you using, also `PROPAGATION_NESTED` only works on certain databases, have you tried `PROPAGATION_REQUIRED` instead.

Comment: We're using mysql 5.5.31, also we're using org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect

Comment: Make sure that your tables are indeed InnoDB tables and not MyISAM tables!

Comment: One thing is that NESTED (afaik) isn't supported on MySQL. NESTED probably doesn't mean what you think it means, I strongly suggest trying 'REQUIRED' instead.

Comment: I think on calling query.executeUpdate() it will complete the transaction and next executeUpdate will be treated as new transaction.it might be the issue.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, I'm trying to check now.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
<prop key="remove*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
```

I don't think all the database server does support the transaction.